# Evaluate the result of a command inside another command

Tags: beamer, biblatex, macros, footnotes

I want to create a new footnote citation command using `biblatex` therefore I use the `\DeclareCiteCommand` for its definition.
Then the command `\printfield{labelnumber}` gives me the number of the citation (according to the `style=numeric`).

But when I want to pass the result of `\printfield{labelnumber}` to the command `\footnotemark` to specify the number I want to print I get an error Missing number. So I assume that the command `\footnotemark` receive the string of the `\printfield{labelnumber}` and not its resulting number.

Thus my question is how to evaluate or pass the result of a command inside another command ?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Harshman1970,
    author = {and others Harshman, Richard A},
    doi = {10.1134/S0036023613040165},
    issn = {00360236},
    journal = {UCLA Working Papers in Phonetics},
    pages = {1--84},
    title = {{Foundations of the PARAFAC procedure: Models and conditions for an" explanatory" multimodal factor analysis}},
    volume = {16},
    year = {1970}
}
@article{Hitchcock1927,
    author = {Hitchcock, Frank L.},
    doi = {10.1002/sapm192761164},
    issn = {0097-1421},
    journal = {Journal of Mathematics and Physics},
    number = {1-4},
    pages = {164--189},
    title = {{The Expression of a Tensor or a Polyadic as a Sum of Products}},
    volume = {6},
    year = {1927}
}   
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\testcommand}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\footnotemark[\printfield{labelnumber}]\footnotetext[1]{\printfield{labelnumber} \printnames{labelname}%
    }}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Slide 1\testcommand{Harshman1970}\testcommand{Hitchcock1927}}
        some text
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\thefield{labelnumber}`. And better use biber as biblatex backend.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes using `thefield` is solving the problem: maybe you can turn your comment in a detailed answer. About the `biber` about it was to make the problem simpler as possible !

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here or do you know a good duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just turning the comment of Ulrike Fischer into an answer.
The substitution of the command `\printfield{labelnumber}` by the command `\thefield{labelnumber}`, can solve this problem.

I do not really have explanation about it, so any other answer is welcomed.